# Is it possible to receive dynamic data from google analytics?

Tags: javascript, http, google-analytics, client

I can send dynamic data from client to Google Analytics.
For example

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
```

But is it possible to receive dynamic data from Google Analytics?
For example, created filter names or variable names something like that?

The goal is to change some value on Google Analytics panel and receive it on the client-side (JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data saved on the Google Analytics panel cannot be changed.

Eventually you can query the data with the Google Analytics API and process them according to your needs before displaying them on the client side.